# How to make a function like bind_param() in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to write a small shell for MySQL, which has some basic functionality which I need for my code. This is for test purposes and to get to know PHP a bit more.

The problem I encounter is the following:

```
bool mysqli_stmt::bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )
```

Above is the exact definition I find on the internet, but I cannot make my function like this (syntax errors, or server says: I need a var of type 'mixed').

```
public function bind($types, $values)
{
    $this->statement->bind_param($types, $values);
}
```

The above is roughly what I would like to achieve, but even with searching the web, I'm unable to find a solution.

Comment: what type is `$values` ?

Comment: Well, is should be a possibility between string, integer, double and blob

Comment: @Rob Biermann Can you post your code bit more detailed? where is the `$this->statement` coming from

Comment: `$this->statement = $this->connection->prepare("Select * from products where productname = ?");
        $product = "t-shirt";
        $this->bind("s" $values);`

This is the way 'statement' is initialized, and how I would like to use the bind function. The trick is I want it to have as many variables as needed(variable amount of variables).

Comment: php5.6+ has [variadic functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) if your version is earlier (or you need compatibility) then `func_get_args()` is the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public function bindParam($types)
{
    /* For types, the next rules count:
    i   corresponding variable has type integer
    d   corresponding variable has type double
    s   corresponding variable has type string
    b   corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
     */
    $fetchedParameters = func_get_args();
    $parameters = "\"$types\"";//Create a variable that holds the types of the statement
    for($i = 1; $i < count($fetchedParameters);$i++)
    {
            $parameters .= ",\$fetchedParameters[$i]";   //Each variable name gets added to parameters(it needs to be the variable name, not the value!!)               
    }
    eval("\$this->statement->bind_param($parameters);");//Assemble the statement and execute it.     
}
```

This is pretty much what I worked out, my parameters are not provided by a user, so there should not be any security issue. This completely resolves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The type "mixed" doesn't exist, it just says that the parameter passed might be string or might be integer or anything. You should write your function with one parameter, $types and all the other parameters come from "func_get_args()".
This passes all the parameters given to the function so you can work with them like an array:

```
function bind_param(string $types)
{
$args = func_get_args();
print_r($args);
}

bind_param("foo", "bar", 123, false, array("a","b"));
```

Note that it will include the first $types parameter too.